# how to create redirect to login if not authorized in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

how to make if the user's token is expired or not authorized it will be redirected to the login page.
I have a problem when I login, if the user token is expired, it should be redirected to the login page, but in this case it doesn't return to the login page, instead it gives an 'exception' error message, is there a code I missed.
Thank you.

```
Future<User?> login(String nim, String password) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    try {
      var body = {
        'username': nim,
        'password': password,
      };
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
          '$url/login_mhs',
        ),
        body: body,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final token = jsonDecode(response.body)['data']['access_token'];
        await UtilSharedPreferences.setToken(token);
        print(token);
        print(await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken());
        return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

and this when doing get data

```
Future<UserBiodata> getDataMahasiswa() async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/biodata',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return UserBiodata.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

this when calling it in the widget

```
TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    final prefs =
                                        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                    prefs.setString(Constant.token, '');
                                    if (nimController.text.isEmpty ||
                                        passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
                                      showError('NIM tidak sesuai');
                                    } else {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isLoading = true;
                                      });
                                      User? user = await Provider.of<Services>(
                                              context,
                                              listen: false)
                                          .login(nimController.text,
                                              passwordController.text);
                                      setState(() {
                                        isLoading = false;
                                      });
                                      if (user == null) {
                                        showError('NIM/Password tidak sesuai');
                                      } else {
                                        userProvider.user = user;
                                        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                          context,
                                          '/main',
                                          (route) => false,
                                        );
                                      }
                                    }
                                  },
                                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                    backgroundColor: primaryColor,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(66),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Login",
                                    style: boldButton,
                                  ),
                                ),
```

this is the result when I have a user whose token is expired or not authorized the result is like this
[image]

Comment: When you know in your code that the token is expired, just right there use Navigator to go to login screen instead of main

Comment: where do i add it?

Comment: From your question it is not clear on How you know that the user token expired if the user has logged in once before?

Comment: Yes, because when I make a request in Postman, the token that is being used in debugging mode automatically expires

Answer (score 1):

Use another if else condition (nested into your else of the event) like below:

```
   if (user == null) {
    showError('NIM/Password tidak sesuai');
    } else {
       if (token_is_not_found_equals_true){
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
           context,
            '/login',
         (route) => false,
          );
           }

   else {
    userProvider.user = user;
     Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
       context,
        '/main',
     (route) => false,
    );
    }
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work well, stay with the same result before

Comment: you need to add token logic by replacing "token_is_not_found_equals_true" in the if condition.

Comment: if (token == null) {
                                          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                                            context,
                                            '/login',
                                            (route) => false,
                                          );
                                        }

Comment: i make it like this

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle is using the package [flutter_modular](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular), there you have a feature call [Route Guard](https://modular.flutterando.com.br/docs/flutter_modular/navegation#route-guard). You check details in it's documentation. It's very easy to understand and implement.

I think it's the cleanest way to handle users unauthorized users.